# How to avoid additional spacing on the x-axis and y-axis

Tags: r, ggplot2

once again I'm stuck, I want to get rid of the additional spacing that is present on the y-axis and the x-axis.

I'm aware that this spacing prevents that some datapoints can interfere with the axis and therefore reduce the readibility of the chart. But right now, I want to get rid of this space that is used in the plottingarea.

Here is my code

```
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(category = c("A", "B"), value=c(3,4))

q <- ggplot(data=df)
q <- q + geom_bar(aes(x=category, y=value, stat="identity"))
q
```

I think breaks would not work because this just an example dataset

[image: sample chart]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
q <- ggplot(data=df,aes(x=category, y=value))
q <- q + geom_bar(stat="identity")
q + scale_x_discrete(expand=c(0,0)) + scale_y_continuous(expand=c(0,0))
```

[image]